# Add widget doesn't work

Tags: gwt, tabpanel

Is there something wrong with my code?
The Tabs that I added won't showed up..
Here's the sample code

```
ReservationUI res = new ReservationUI();
    SeatUI seat = new SeatUI();

    TabPanel reserveTabs = new TabPanel();
    reserveTabs.setPixelSize(600, 250);
    reserveTabs.setAnimScroll(true);
    reserveTabs.setTabScroll(true);
    add(reserveTabs);

    reserveTabs.add(res, "Restaurvation");
    reserveTabs.add(seat, "Seat");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a widget and it does not show up, most often the problem is with the height. In this case you set it explicitly on your TabPanel, but if the parent widget has a height of zero, the TabPanel won't be visible.

You either have to add it to a widget that implements ProvidesResize interface (LayoutPanel, VerticalPanel, etc.) and has a height of more than zero, or set the height of the parent widget explicitly.